# How do I show this is a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $\beta$ is a basis for $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$ and let $a \in \mathbb R$, $a \neq 1$.

Show that $a \beta= ${$ay\ |\ y \in \beta$} is a basis for $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$ for all $a \neq 0$.

Okay, isn't the dimension of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$ uncountably infinite? How can I show it's a basis using the original method (linear independence and spanning), if the dimension is uncountable. Or should I approach it by contradiction?

Comment: The given set is a basis iff it spans the whole space $\;\Bbb R_{\Bbb Q}\;$ **and** if it is linearly independent, meaning any *finite* subset is linearly independent.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, that's right, but how can I show that if it's uncountable? For instance, how can I take a finite subset out? Usually I would index the vectors by the natural numbers, but this basis isn't countable. Maybe I'm overthinking it, but I'm still confused

Comment: Just take *any* finite set $\;\{ay\;;\;y\in S\subset\beta\;,\;|S|<\aleph_0\}\;$...what's the problem? No need to subindex stuff here.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you. So linear independence is easily seen because $a \neq 0$ for all $a$, right? Can you give me a hint on how spanning will work? Usually I take any element $v$ in $\mathbb R$ and show that it can be written as a finite linear combination of vectors in $\beta$.

Comment: This might be long so I'll write an answer, @Alti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$x\in\Bbb R\implies \exists\;\text{finite}\;S\subset\beta \;\;s.t.\;\; x=\sum_{s\in S}a_ss\;,\;\;a_s\in\Bbb Q\;,\;s\in S\implies$$

$$x=\sum_{x\in S}\frac{a_s}a(as)\;,\;\;s\in S$$

and thus we can see any real is a rational linear combination of elements in $\;a\beta\;$ ...

The above works *only* for $\;a\in\Bbb Q\;$ . For $\;a\in\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q\;$ I can't see the way...

Comment: I'll try to build off what you have, Thank you!